# Only displaying input value after button click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a simple React form that, on button click, will display the entered input value in a controlled input element.  Specifically, I do NOT want to have an identical solution to that in the React docs (constantly updating the displayed value on input change), rather I only want it to update the displayed paragraph text after the user has hit the submit button. I am able to do this with this current solution (conditionally rendering based on submitted state that is set in handler functions):

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(true);
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSubmitted(false);
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <label>Text: </label>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Show
        </button>
        {submitted && <p>{text}</p>}
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

But I am guessing that there is a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to submit multiple times and keep the last before submitting again, use this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDisplayText(text);
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <label>Text: </label>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Show
        </button>
        {displayText && <p>{displayText}</p>}
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

`displayText && ...` is so that the paragraph tag doesn't exist until it has a value to display, but you can just replace that section with out that and it will work.

Comment: Your code made me notice a typo in my own within handleChange: setName should be setText (and I think setSubmitted should be removed from your solution).  That aside, thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for.